# SFMC SDK is not configured correctly

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

I have a problem with the initialization of **MarketingCloudSDK** **iOS** on version **8.1.2**, but the same problem is also in **8.1.1** and **8.1.0**. My project is written in SwiftUI and I use the **App** protocol for starting the app. Then I'm using `UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor` to connect `AppDelegate` with that SwiftUI app. I'm using SPM.

I followed the **LearningApp** which is part of the **MarketingCloudSDK** package. I have copied that logic from `AppDelegate`, but I always get this error:
[image]

And yes, I have already implemented those two functions and they are called correctly, `deviceToken` is returned and set to the `SFMCSdk` in that `requestPushSdk` closure.

If I then try to `print(SFMCSdk.mp.deviceToken())` it returns the **deviceToken**.

Also, the console log returns confirmation, that `deviceToken` was set correctly:

```
log: device token has been set in the SDK with value: <token> file: MarketingCloudSDKFoundation.m line: line: 1428
```

PS: I suspect the combination of SwiftUI `App` protocol and `UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor`, but I hope the problem is elsewhere.

So please, if anyone knows what I am doing wrong, let me know. Thanks!

**EDIT: Today I tried to move the main starting point using `@UIApplicationMain` in `AppDelegate` instead of `@main` in the implemented `App` protocol and this error is gone!
But this is not a solution for me, I can't rewrite the entry point because of one SDK, so I hope guys from Salesforce tell me the solution or fix the issue. Thanks!**