# [Xcode][SPM] Failed to resolve Dependencies version 8.0.13

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios, mobilepush-ios

today I found out that I can't resolve any other than the newest (8.1.2) version of **MarketingCloudSDK-iOS**.

SPM says this when I try to resolve **8.0.13** version:

```
Failed to resolve dependencies Dependencies could not be resolved because no versions of 'marketingcloudsdk-ios' match the requirement 8.0.13..<8.1.0 and 'infrastructure' depends on 'marketingcloudsdk-ios' 8.0.13..<8.1.0.
```

This worked last week.

Can someone tell me where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are able to see the dependency resolved, please find the screenshot below
[image]

Thanks,
Prakashini

Comment: I see, it's bizarre because I can resolve that in my second project, but it still can't be resolved in the main where I needed that dependency. My project probably has another problem, but the latest version works, so I can mark your answer as resolved. Thanks!

Comment: More important is my second question here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/418774/sfmc-sdk-is-not-configured-correctly, can you look at it, please?